# Purpose of SupportLibrary

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-support-library

I wasn't using `SupportLibrary` until saw new Facebook API that uses method only with Support Fragments so I changed all of them to Support.
The question: is using SupportFragments is "must-be" for Android developer then?

Yes I saw documentation:
http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It entirely depends on your target devices. But some libraries depend on the support library because they have chosen to support older devices as well.

You can always restrict your minSDKVersion to avoid supporting older devices. You may have to tweak the minSDKVersions of the libraries you use as well if they come with an AndroidManifest.xml as well.

```
android:minSdkVersion
```

Check out the documentation on this:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#apilevel

Comment: Yes, and what to do in this situation when my project if from 4.0 and Facebook API wants me to use them? Maybe better all the time to use it so that in future there would be no need to change code?

Comment: Updated my answer, let me know if that helps

Answer (score 2):

To support some of the Latest Features like Fragments(Added in 3.0), Material Design(Added in 5.0)  to old Devices, support Library is useful. There are lot of features coming in new versions , so in order to support those features for the older devices these support Libs are handy to use and update your app

Answer (score 2):

Is not a must if your App is not going to be running on older Android e.g. 1.6, 2 etc, therefore doesn't need backward-compatibility otherwise it's a must to use Support Libraries